# Can I see registers after model test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm new in Ruby on Rails and testing and I'm doign some model tests.

After using `rails test` command and the test passed, I made a query to the affected tables, but it's empty (there are only two empty registers but no the test ones).

My test code it's this:

```
test "sign up successful username-pw" do
    params =  { "username": "acme", "password": "foo123" }
    user = User.new(params)
    assert user.save
end
```

I'm worried about the results because I added in the seed file more registers but I can't see if really are used in the test (according with the results, they didn't).

Is it normal the empty test database or it's something that I'm not considering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed in `config/database.yml`, in Rails you have 3 environments (`development`, `test` and `production`) with 3 different databases.

That is why the data you've added in your seed file is not reflected in your `test` environment.

You can apply your seed file to your `test` database using the following command:

```
rails db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```